# Surface of the Gabriel's horn with cilinder or with cone's section

Tags: integration, volume

So, I am sure y'all familiar with **Gabriel's horn**, and when I looked up for the surface of it, the integral is based of a section of a cone but not a cylinder, even though a cylinder was used for the volume.

Moreover, by using a cylinder, the fact that the surface is infinite does not change.

Then **why** is a **section of cone** used for the **surface** and not the **volume**, and why a **cylinder** is used for the **volume** and not for the **surface** in order to calculate the surface and volume of Gabriel's horn ?

Comment: This type of question has been asked a large number of times over the years; [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510491/volumes-surface-areas-of-sphere-with-calculus-paradox) contains a good explanation, and looks reasonably representative. Not marking as a duplicate because you may want to search for yourself.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Gabriel's horn. You're trying to understand how one computes surface area and volume with integrals. Back up a step to curves $y=f(x)$: Why do we use rectangles to approximate/compute the area under the curve but chords (trapezoids) to approximate/compute the length of the curve?

Answer (score 0):

So, this question was already asked in a way, by this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510491/volumes-surface-areas-of-sphere-with-calculus-paradox), thus I mark my question as solved

link to the already asked and answered question : [link to the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510491/volumes-surface-areas-of-sphere-with-calculus-paradox)

thanks to Andrew D. Hwang for the link to this question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).